# R- could not find function "tokenize"

Tags: r, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize a sentence. I have installed the openNLP and the NLP packages but when I'm trying to run the tokenize function on a sentence I'm getting the below array:

```
        Error: could not find function "tokenize"     
        > library(NLP)
        > library(openNLP)
        > s
         [1] "This is a sentence."
        > tokenize(s,"en") 
          Error: could not find function "tokenize"
```

Thanks

Comment: Where did you come up with the code?

Comment: it seems that the tokenize() function, that was available in openNLP v0.0 is not anymore in v0.2

Answer (score 2):

I have `NLP` version 0.1-7 and `openNLP` version 0.2-5 installed on my computer. There is not a function named **tokenize** anymore in the `openNLP` package. You can ask the maintainer about the old function.

Alternatively, you can perform the following:

```
install.packages("sos")
library(sos)
???tokenize
```

`???tokenize` will search for the keyword **tokenize** in R packages, but look at the date. You will see that **tokenize** is listed under `openNLP` in 2012. You may find other functions in other packages that perform the task(s) that you are seeking.